# Lower bound Sum of Complex Exponentials using derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I wish to either prove or disprove the following conjecture.
**Conjecture.**
Let $f(x)$ be a trigonometric polynomial. Specifically,
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{J}\alpha_j e^{2\pi i k_j x},
$$
where $k_j \in \mathbf{R}$ for all $j$. Additionally, suppose that $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$. Then there exists positive constants $c', d, \delta$ such that
$$
|f(x)| \geq c'\,|x-x_0|^d
$$
for all $x\in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$.

Here are my current ideas.

**Ideas.** We know that $f(x)$ will equal its Taylor series. Hence, let us consider it's Taylor series. First observe the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $f(x)$ be a trigonometric polynomial defined as above. Additionally, suppose that $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x\in [0,1]$. Then there exists some $n \leq J-1$ such that $f^{(n)}(x_0) \ne 0$.

*Proof Idea.* It suffices to consider the system such that $f^{(n)}(x_0) = 0$ for $n=0,\ldots, J$. One will obtain a *Vandermonde-like* system which has linearly independent columns (when considering the augmented matrix). Hence, for all those derivatives to be zero would require $f \equiv 0$, which is a contradiction.

**Potential Proof of the Conjecture.** Let us assume that $d \leq J-1$ is the smallest positive integer such that $f^{(d)}(x_0) \ne 0.$ Therefore, we have that

$$
f(x) = \frac{f^{(d)}(x_0)}{d!}(x-x_0)^d + R_{d+1}(x).
$$
Recall the Lagrange form of the Remainder.
$$
R_{d+1}(x) = \frac{f^{(d+1)}(c)}{d!}(x-x_0)^{d+1}
$$
for some $c$ between $x$ and $x_0$. Therefore, we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{f^{d}(x_0)}{d!}(x-x_0)^d + \frac{f^{d+1}(c)}{(d+1)!}(x-x_0)^{d+1}
\\
&= (x-x_0)^d \left(\frac{f^{d}(x_0)}{d!} + \frac{f^{d+1}(c)}{(d+1)!}(x-x_0)\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, it suffices to bound
$$
\left|\frac{f^{d}(x_0)}{d!} + \frac{f^{d+1}(c)}{(d+1)!}(x-x_0)\right|
$$
from below. Note that the aforementioned function only has a zero when $x = x_0 - \frac{d f^{d}(x_0)}{f^{d+1}(c)}$. Also note that $\frac{d f^{d}(x_0)}{f^{d+1}(c)}$ may not even be real-valued. However, if we let $\delta < \left|\frac{d f^{d}(x_0)}{f^{d+1}(c)}\right|$, we can guarantee that
$$
\left|\frac{f^{d}(x_0)}{d!} + \frac{f^{d+1}(c)}{(d+1)!}(x-x_0)\right|
$$
obtains a nonzero minimum for $x\in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. Let $c' = \min \left|\frac{f^{d}(x_0)}{d!} + \frac{f^{d+1}(c)}{(d+1)!}(x-x_0)\right|$ for $x\in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. Hence,

$$
|f(x)| \geq c' |x-x_0|^d
$$
for $x \in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$.

**Questions.** Does this proof work? Or is there a glaring mistake somewhere? Is this already known? In my cursory literature search I couldn't quite find this exact result, but I didn't look very hard. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot apply Lagrange's form of remainder for complex-valued function.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know if the claim is true at all?

Comment: You probably want the $k_j$ to be integers?

Comment: The $k_j$ are real valued and not integers with the problem I'm working on.

Comment: $f$ is a complex analytic function (entire) and is not identically zero so if the order of the zero at $x_0$ is $n>0$ then $\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}$ is also entire and non zero at $x_0$ so it is at least $c>0$ in absolute value near $x_0$ by continuity so you are done; btw if $k_j$ are not integers, it is technically not correct to call $f$ trigonometric polynomial as it is generally not periodic anymore

Comment: Oh It was my understanding that when you deal with a sum of complex exponentials of any frequency its a trigonometric polynomial. What would the correct term for it be? Or is there not one frequently used?

Comment: I think these (when $k_j$ are not integers) are called nonharmonic complex exponential polynomials and there is a very interesting theory associated with them - there is a book by R Young An Introduction to Non Harmonic Fourier Series that discusses lots of stuff about such

Comment: Interesting! I will have to take a look. Also, do we know anything about for which $x$ the desired inequality holds? In other words, can we quantify the $\delta$ such that $|f(x)|\geq c |x-x_0|$ for $|x-x_0|<\delta$? Does it have any relation to how many terms we are adding together or is it just a detached quantity?

Comment: $\delta$ (in the sense of there is a $c_{\delta}$ for which the above holds) clearly depends on the distance from $x_0$ to the nearest zero of $f$ since $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}$ being continuous will be inferiorly bounded away from $0$ on compacts as long as it is non zero; on the other hand $c$ depends on the minimum of $g$, so in particular on the value of the first non zero derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ etc

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that $\delta$ is not well defined in terms of $f$ and $x_0$, because $c$ depends on $x$. But you can modify this because you know that $f^{d+1}$ is continuous, so you can substitute $|f^{d+1}(c)|$ by the supremum of $|f^{d+1}|$ over a small interval around $x_0$, thus,
$$ \delta <\min{1,\frac{|f^{d}(x_0)|}{\sup_{s\in I} |f^{d+1}(s)|}}, $$
where $I=(x_0-1,x_0+1)$ (in general, you can substitute $1$ by $\varepsilon$ depending on the interval on which the function is $C^{d+1}$).

The rest looks fine. The function is of one real variable, so I think Lagrange’s form of the remainder still works.

Answer (score 0):

It follows immediately from your lemma, since Taylor's theorem implies that the vanishing of the function value and the first $n$ derivatives at $x_0$ is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n} = 0$

Comment: I'm slightly misunderstanding how $\lim_{x\to  x_0} \frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$ gives rise to a lower bound. My first impression is that it gives an upper bound. Specifically, for $|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)| < \epsilon |x-x_0|^n.$

Comment: @Doofenshmert: Taylor's theorem says that the $n$-th Taylor polynomial is the unique polynomial of degree $\le n$ which approximates $f$ with an error of the order of $o(|x-x_0|^n)$, i.e., with $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-T(x)}{(x-x_0)^n} = 0$. The assumption that this limit is 0 shows that $T$ is the zero polynomial, so that all the derivatives up to order $n$ are zero.